# Java.lang.error?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I encountered a error Java.lang.error when trying to access a static function in a class.

```
class Global
{
   public Global(){}
   public static void Init()
   {
      //doing something
   }
}
```

I use Global class here:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyApp app = new MyApp ();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyApp ()
    {
           //invoke
           Global.Init(); //throw Java.lang.error
    }
}
```

The error is thrown whenever I access any static properties in class Global.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax errors:

- Class instead of class
- Global() instead of Global

I suggest you read a Java Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Luca ^^ But it is not main problem :) i have edited code ^^

Answer (score 1):

An Error is thrown if an unrecoverable problem is detected. Something bad must be happening in your `Init` method.

Comment: It is not as you think, Mathias Schwarz. The error is thrown even if when the Init() method do nothing.

Answer (score -2):

I use Global class here:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyApp app = new MyApp ();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyApp ()
    {
       Global.Init();
    }
}
```

Especially, The error was thrown whenever I access any static properties in class Global.

Thank all!